# How can I replace a specific part of an URL with Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, url, replace, substitution

I tried a lot of things with Regexextract and Substitute but I can't get it to work so I hope someone can help me on this.

We have a link structure with the category name in the second '/ /' part of the url. In Google Sheets I want to replace this with the category name: 'dagdeals'. How can I do this? Just to give an example:

https://trips.holidayguru.nl/packages/nederland/cd4ea4f1-3189-4a60-8ad1-60e1a15bdccf/
Here 'nederland' should be replaced with 'dagdeals'

https://trips.holidayguru.nl/packages/weekendje-weg/4fbce498-cb07-4032-94e4-903bb29af772/
Here 'weekendje-weg' should be replaced with 'dagdeals'

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=index(substitute(A:A,ifna(regexextract(A:A,"(?:/([^/]+)){3}")),"dagdeals"))
```

OR

```
=index(ifna(regexreplace(A:A,"(//.*?/.*?/)([^/]+)(.*)","$1dagdeals$3")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, both of them work!

So just to understand the formula better: (?:/([^/]+)){3} selects the third element / text within two '/' (slashes). Is that correct?